# Runtime multiplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

HI, I have a products model and a dealers model . I am creating an app in which a dealer selects a product and then he's routed to purchase order form . I want to create a dynamic multiplication of Products*Price = Total price i.e. when the form opens , he adds the quantity of the product and the default price is multiplied with no. of products to give total price.

What shall I do ?

Please guide. Thanks

Comment: what version of ruby and rails, and what JavaScript framework are you using?

Comment: Have you written any code yet? If so, can you post it up, particularly the views. This is really a javascript query (and quite simple). Are you using a javascript library?

Comment: I am using rails 3 and the default javascript library

Comment: It is not a big deal but first you have to try it by using javascript. I suggest jquery framework.... When user select any product then u can have the product information at ur form.. where you can give the drop down for selection of quantity. When user select any quantity then just update the price dom by multiplying quantity with selected product price....

Comment: You really should have a shot yourself at coding it and we can assist in ironing out bugs. What you need to do is have an input field on the order form and whenever the value of that input field changes, a piece of javascript is called that looks up the price of the product; multiplies by the quantity and updates another field on the order form.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good guides out there for Rails 3 and Unobtrusive Javascript (UJS). Here's one that starts you from the ground up:

> http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/